# Duplicate line coming in the next page of pdf document in iText

Tags: java, itext

I am using the iText pdf library, **iText version is 2.1.7 (com.lowagie)** to generate the pdf. While generating the pdf document, **the last line of the first page comes in the first line of the next page**. I provide below the image for reference. In my pdf generation, in some places I am using table to display the data and in some places, I am using Paragraph for text rendering. I also want to inform that the text will be html type text where there will be many hyperlinks.

Please help me in this regard about how to address.

Image is given below.

[image: Duplicate line in next page]

Comment: Can you please add the corresponding code ? In the form of a [mcve] ;)

Comment: Also, there is no support whatsoever for a version of iText that dates from 2009. In the almost 8 years that have passed since the version you are using was released, we have fixed numerous bugs. We are now at iText version 7! If you can reproduce the problem with iText 5.5.10 or iText 7.0.1, we might get a look at the problem, but since you're using an obsolete version, you're on your own.

Comment: Furthermore, you might want to wait for the upcoming release. In iText 2.1.7, there is very poor support for HTML. In iText 5, we had XML Worker that was already better (e.g. support for CSS), but it still had many limitations. When we rewrote iText for iText 7, we had XML Worker in mind (e.g. support for inheriting styles) and we almost finished the iText 7 port of XML Worker. In other words: you can save yourself a lot of coding misery if you just wait for another week or so.

Comment: @Debadatta I think I remember that there were check-ins in the 5.x.x iText code that according to their comments fixed problems described similar to yours. Thus, you should indeed check whether the problem does not occur anymore after updating to iText 5.5.10 and adapting to the differences, in particular the different package names.

Comment: @Sambit I have the same issue now with iTextSharp 4.1.6.16. Have you solved this problem back then?

Answer (score 1):

I investigated and isolated the issue. Below is the code to reproduce it (code is in C# but I assume it works the same in Java version of the library). At the end of the answer I provide a workaround that fixes it.

```
var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 50 /* must be bigger or equal than height of row for bug to occur */, 20);
var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
document.Open();
document.NewPage();
var table = new PdfPTable(1) { SplitLate = false };

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.AddElement(new Phrase("Header " + i));

    var innerTable = new PdfPTable(1);
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        innerTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Inner cell " + (i*10+j))) { MinimumHeight = 25 });
    }
    cell.AddElement(innerTable);
    table.AddCell(cell);
}

document.Add(table);
pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;
document.Close();
```

There are two conditions that must be met for the bug to occur:

1. Top margin must be bigger or equal than row height
2. There must be a `Phrase` (probably any non-table element in fact) in the cell of outer table

The result is:
[image: bug on pagebreak]

It's probably caused by bug in code checking if there is space for a row and specifically in handling margin there.

After further investigation it turned out that the issue won't occur if we wrap the element in dummy table:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var cell = new PdfPCell();
    var wrapperTable = new PdfPTable(1) { WidthPercentage = 100 };
    wrapperTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
    wrapperTable.AddCell(new Phrase("Header " + i));
    cell.AddElement(wrapperTable);

    var innerTable = new PdfPTable(1);
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        innerTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Inner cell " + (i*10+j))) { MinimumHeight = 25 });
    }
    cell.AddElement(innerTable);
    table.AddCell(cell);
}
```

Resulting in:
[image: fixed pagebreak]